# Import Data From Excel To SQL Server via ASP.NET Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need an ASP.net web application for importing and displaying Excel data , I searched for it on internet but no one was clear or working for me , could you help please?

Comment: The keyword for your requirements is ETL.
This could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046259/asp-net-automated-manual-etl-process

Answer (score 1):

This has a free community pack of components (if you or your company meets requeriments)

http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/web/FlatSpreadsheet/Sample/ShowCase